# Ubuntu Gnome cant find wired connection

Tags: networking, drivers

I have been studying Linux and CentOs for some time now and figured I am going to try installing a server with some kind of Linux distribution. My friend told me that CentOs is not good, so I figured I could try something new, he recommended Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu Gnome and Ubuntu I am now going to try to install Ubuntu Server but I get same problem - the wired connection is not working.

I've read on forums the last 4 days and I just cant, I give up, I cant do it myself. I need help. I read these commands are good and supply a lot of information for troubleshooting:

```
root@GusServer:/# cat /etc/network/interfaces
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

root@GusServer:/# cat /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf cat: /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf: No such file or directory

root@GusServer:/# ifconfig -a 
lo     Link encap:Local Loopback
       inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 
       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 
       RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
       TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
       RX bytes:11263 (11.2 KB) TX bytes:11263 (11.2 KB)

root@GusServer:/# lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)  
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)  
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)  
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)  
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d4)  
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B85 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)  
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)  
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)  
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
```

All I want to do is just have a HTTP and FTP-server, distribution doesnt matter I just need a Linux-based OS that CAN WORK ....

Comment: You don't seem to have a network interface. Could this be a hardware problem?

Comment: Before I installed Ubuntu I had Windows Server 2012 R2 and the internet connection (wired, I dont have wireless) worked just fine. I dont have a external NIC, its all on the Motherboard: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4569#sp

Comment: AFAIK realtek lan is supported out of the box. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Check BIOS settings to see if on-board lan is enabled. Otherwise it may well be a hardware failure.

Comment: on-board LAN was disabled. I have now changed it to enabled, if I understand it correctly that is my NIC. The question is, how the fudge did it get disable?

Wow, how can I be so dumb... Its working now, thats embarassing.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't be embarrassed: you gave us exactly the right information to figure out what was wrong.